# image steganography- hiding an image within an image

Tags: matlab, steganography

There is something wrong with this code after the figure 3 is displayed. The two images are not getting added. How to correct it? This program hides a message image in the lower bit planes of a cover image read in cover image filename

```
%covername = input('Enter image file name with extension (like jennifer.bmp): ', 's'); 
%read in message image filename 
%messagename = input('Enter message image file name with extension: ', 's'); 
%open cover and message image files 
cover = imread('hand.jpg'); 
message = imread('coins.png'); 
%display on screen the two images 
figure(1), imshow(cover); title('Original Image (Cover Image)'); 
figure(2), imshow(message);title('Image to Hide (Message Image)'); 
%change to double to work with addition below 
cover=double(cover); 
message=double(message); 
%imbed = no. of bits of message image to embed in cover image 
imbed=4; 
%shift the message image over (8-imbed) bits to right 
messageshift=bitshift(message,-(8-imbed)); 
%show the message image with only embed bits on screen 
%must shift from LSBs to MSBs 
showmess=uint8(messageshift); 
showmess=bitshift(showmess,8-imbed); 
figure(3),imshow(showmess);title('4 Bit Image to Hide'); 
%now zero out imbed bits in cover image 
coverzero = cover; 
for i=1:imbed 
coverzero=bitset(coverzero,i,0); 
end 
cove=uint8(coverzero);
%now add message image and cover image 
stego = imadd(cove,messageshift); 
figure(4),imshow(stego);title('Stego image'); 
%save files if need to
%4 bit file that was embedded = same as file extracted 
imwrite(showmess,'showmess4.bmp');           
%use bmp to preserve lower bits
%jpg will get rid of them
%stego file imwrite(stego,'stego4.bmp');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is imadd gives you the error "X and Y must have the same size and class or Y must be a scalar double". This hints that your images are not similar.

If you do `whos cove messageshift`, you will see that cove is class uint8, while messageshift is double. Just convert messageshift to uint8 in line 16, like you did with cove:

`messageshift=uint8(bitshift(message,-(8-imbed)));`